# ITerm Shows Broken Pipe Message

Tags: macos, iterm

How can I get rid of this alert?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the specific notification in *System Preferences » Growl* by unchecking *Enabled*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's great. I've never actually opened Growl preferences before except to change the theme. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using iTerm2. This has apparently been fixed, though it's not in the current beta. I'm assuming the latest nightly build will have the fix included, but I've not tried it. It bugged me, so I just turned off Growl notifications for iTerm - didn't see much benefit of having them.

http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=358

Comment: good point plus 1